# Favor resolver un problema de basic

Tags: basic

Necesito resolver: elaborar un formulario en el cual me permita conocer cuando el ingreso de de valores entre 1 y 10 y que en casa caso me muestre un mensaje Distinto para cada Calificación . el mismo puede ser elaborado bajo cual quier versión de visual basic.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Hacer programa Visual Basic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/543258/hacer-programa-visual-basic)

Comment: ¿Por qué duplicar la pregunta?, mejor por favor atiende a las observaciones hechas